# Set up a static MAC for 4G modem

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking

I am using a ZTE MF823 modems and I need to have some sort of unique identifiers for them, since they are all shipped with dynamically generated MACs and serial numbers I am trying to create a static MAC inside the modem. 
Does that sound doable, or am I wasting my time even digging into this? Thank you

I need to do this because-
Each modem has a different IP

```
usb1 - 192.168.10.1
usb2 - 192.168.11.1
```

When server starts I am adding specific routing rules to each modem

```
192.168.*10*.0/24 dev usb*10* proto kernel scope link src 192.168.*10*.100
192.168.*11*.0/24 dev usb*11* proto kernel scope link src 192.168.*11*.100
```

So that I could send traffic to each modem separately.
And because they are plugged into a usb hub boot order is always random so every modem **must** have an appropriate name.
I know it is quite possible to achieve that with udev rules, but that would mean each modem cannot be plugged into a different slot.

P.s modem is running busybox.

Comment: Hi, the broadband provider can usually allow all the modem you have, what specific case you are working on that need to hack the modem ?

Comment: Added a use case explanation.